# Do I need Schengen visa type c?

Tags: schengen-visas, connecting-flights, egypt

I am Egyptian with an F1 visa. I will be traveling from the USA to Egypt, and my itinerary includes two transits, one in Lisbon and another in Paris. Both transits are less than 4 hours, during which I will remain within the international transit areas.

I checked and don't need a transit visa for either(correct me if I am wrong please). Yet, I came across some contradictory information that has left me confused "Travelers that need to land in more than one airport of the Schengen territory should apply for a regular Schengen visa instead of a transit Schengen visa". Is the statement meant for people who are required to have a transit visa but had to make more than one? Or do I actually need to get a Schengen visa?

Lastly, I saw one of the requirements is to have travel insurance. Is that also for visa holders only?

PS: I contacted the airline and they said they believe I don't need I am waiting for the consultant in the USA to reply with clear info rather than links.

Comment: If you fly from Lisbon to Paris, that is an internal Schengen flight, and you would have to enter the Schengen area to do it, which implies a visa.

Comment: Do you mean that you have a transit in Lisbon on your way to Egypt and a transit in Paris on your way back to the US (or vice versa)? Or do you mean that on a single trip you will fly US-Lisbon-Paris-Egypt? The former itinerary probably does not require a visa; the latter almost certainly does. See also [Do I need a visa to transit (or layover) in the Schengen area?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/30569/do-i-need-a-visa-to-transit-or-layover-in-the-schengen-area)

Comment: Thank you so much I really appreciate your answer. It is the latter US-Lisbon-Paris-Egypt. Would I need Schengen visa short stay or just a transit visa?

Comment: Oh, I read the question you sent and it is so helpful. I just hoped I knew before I'd need a Schengen visa as I had a flight that is only Paris and Egypt but with a layover and I didn't go with it. Thank you a lot

Comment: Is this on one ticket? This is a rather odd routing.

Comment: "during which I will remain within the international transit areas": no you won't!  @KristvanBesien this sort of thing is actually fairly common.  I often see flights to/from Sarajevo via both Austria and Germany.  If the Egypt-Paris flight and Lisbon-US flights are both full, for example, this is the result.

Comment: Yes, but Lisbon is a Star Alliance hub, whereas Paris is a Skyteam hub. This does make me suspect that this is a combination of two tickets, like Kiwi sells, which comes with its own set of complications....

Answer (score 13):

> "Travelers that need to land **in more than one airport** of the Schengen territory should apply for a regular Schengen visa instead of a transit Schengen visa"

A flight between Lisbon and Paris is a domestic/internal flight **within** the Schengen Area.

To reach the Lisbon flight to Paris, you must therefore enter the Schengen Area since the flight **will not leave** from within the international (non Schengen) part of the airport.

> do I actually need to get a Schengen visa?

Yes, since Egyptian citizens require a visa to enter the Schengen Area.